# Query Execution in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

How to execute query within `format()` function in Postgres?  can any one please guide me.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  format ('select id 
         from '||some_table||' where emp_id 
             ='||QUOTE_LITERAL(m_emp_id)||' ) 
              ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may combine `EXECUTE FORMAT` and an `IF` condition using `GET DIAGNOSTICS`

Here's an example which you can reuse with minimal changes.I have passed table name using `%I` identifier and parameterised argument (`$1`)  for `employee_id`. This is safe against SQL Injection.`LIMIT 1` is used since we are interested if at least one row exists. This will improve query performance and is equivalent(or efficient) to using `EXISTS` for huge datasets with multiple matching rows.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
some_table TEXT := 'employees';
m_emp_id    INT := 100;
cnt         INT;
BEGIN

 EXECUTE  format ('select 1 
                    from %I where employee_id 
                        = $1 LIMIT 1',some_table  ) USING m_emp_id ;

GET DIAGNOSTICS cnt = ROW_COUNT;

IF cnt > 0
THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'FOUND';
ELSE
     RAISE NOTICE 'NOT FOUND';
END IF;

END 
$$;
```

Result

```
NOTICE:  FOUND
DO
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Kaushik Nayak reply is correct - I will try just little bit more explain this issue.

PLpgSQL knows two types of queries to database:

- static (embedded) SQL - SQL is written directly to plpgsql code. Static SQL can be parametrized (can use a varible), but the parameters should be used as table or column identifier. The semantic (and execution plan) should be same every time.
- dynamic SQL - this style of queries is similar to classic client side SQL - SQL is written as string expression (that is evaluated) in running time, and result of this string expression is evaluated as SQL query. There are not limits for parametrization, but there is a risk of SQL injections (parameters must be sanitized against SQL injection (good examples are in @Kaushik Nayak reply)). More, there is a overhead with every time replanning - so dynamic SQL should be used only when it is necessary. Dynamic SQL is processed by `EXECUTE` command. The syntax of `IF` commands is:

  ```
  IF expression THEN
    statements; ...
  END IF;
  ```

You cannot to place into expression PLpgSQL statements. So this task should be divided to more steps:

```
EXECUTE format(...) USING m_emp_id;
GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
IF cnt > 0 THEN
  ...
END IF;
```